# функция для массива типа double

Tags: c, массивы, функции, указатели, double

Здавствуйте, есть функция, которая переставляет элементы массива в обратном порядке. Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long double array[] =
{
    0.304411824158121,
    0.702270983146229,
    0.675987113307883,
    0.652289676782947,
    0.975411752562938,
    0.284802741036713,
    0.877898595240810,
    0.726726914957288,
    0.084725908720116,
    0.946546040643011
};

void revarray(void*, unsigned long, unsigned long);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    revarray(array, 10, sizeof(long double));
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%.15Lf\n", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void revarray(void* base, unsigned long nel, unsigned long width)
{
    void* ptr = malloc(width);
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int len = 0;

    if (nel % 2 == 0)
    {
        len = nel / 2;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            memccpy(ptr, base + (nel - i - 1)*width, nel, width);
            memccpy(base + (nel - i - 1)*width, base + i * width, nel, width);
            memccpy(base + i * width, ptr, nel, width);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        len = nel / 2 + 1;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (i == len - 1)
            {
                break;
            }

            memccpy(ptr, base + i * width, nel, width);
            memccpy(base + i * width, base + (nel - i - 1)*width, nel, width);
            memccpy(base + (nel - i - 1)*width, ptr, nel, width);
        }
    }

    free(ptr);
}
```

Не подскажите, почему функция не работает для вещественных чисел, выводит всё нулями.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простите уж, разбираться в ваших наворотах...
Почему бы не поступить проще?

```
void revarray(long double * arr, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0, j = size-1; i < j; ++i, --j)
    {
        long double tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Если уж так нужна обобщенность -

```
void rev_array(void * arr, int count, int size)
{
    unsigned char * x = (unsigned char *)arr;
    for(int i = 0, j = count-1; i < j; ++i, --j)
    {
        unsigned char * from = x + i*size;
        unsigned char * to   = x + j*size;
        for(int k = 0; k < size; ++k)
        {
            unsigned char tmp = from[k];
            from[k] = to[k];
            to[k] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот вызов:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%.15Lf\n", array[i]);
    }

    puts("");
    puts("");
    puts("");
    puts("");

    rev_array(array, 10, sizeof(long double));

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%.15Lf\n", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: нужно функцию составить

Comment: void revarray(void *base, unsigned long nel, unsigned long width) 
{ 
        ... 
}

Comment: Нет вопросов, см. дополненный ответ.

Comment: http://ideone.com/La56eX

Comment: спасибо Вам, разобрася

Answer (score 0):

Как-то слишком сложно и непонятно всё :) Если уж так хочется с неопределёнными данными работать, то:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static long double array[] = {
    0.304411824158121,
    0.702270983146229,
    0.675987113307883,
    0.652289676782947,
    0.975411752562938,
    0.284802741036713,
    0.877898595240810,
    0.726726914957288,
    0.084725908720116,
    0.946546040643011 };

static void rev_array( void *array, size_t nelem, size_t width )
{
    size_t i, j;
    char *data = ( char * )array;
    char *tmp = malloc( width );

    for( i = 0, j = nelem - 1; i < j; i++, j-- ) {
        memcpy( tmp, data + j * width, width );
        memcpy( data + j * width, data + i * width, width );
        memcpy( data + i * width, tmp, width );
    }
    free( tmp );
}

static void print_array( long double *array, size_t size )
{
    size_t i;
    for( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        printf( "%.15Lf\n", array[i] );
    }
}

int main()
{
    print_array( array, sizeof( array ) / sizeof( array[0] ) );
    rev_array( array, sizeof( array ) / sizeof( array[0] ), sizeof( array[0] ) );
    printf( "---\n" );
    print_array( array, sizeof( array ) / sizeof( array[0] ) );
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод, оно же тут: http://ideone.com/BLRIY2

```
0.304411824158121
0.702270983146229
0.675987113307883
0.652289676782947
0.975411752562938
0.284802741036713
0.877898595240810
0.726726914957288
0.084725908720116
0.946546040643011
---
0.946546040643011
0.084725908720116
0.726726914957288
0.877898595240810
0.284802741036713
0.975411752562938
0.652289676782947
0.675987113307883
0.702270983146229
0.304411824158121
```

Comment: C одним дополнением - я бы выделял память на стеке.

Comment: @Pink Tux если я правильно понял, пробовал запустить, также нули

Comment: @MeloDy. значит, вам прямая дорога под отладчик. Вывод того, что у меня - см. в ответе.

Comment: @Pink Tux Спасибо, это у меня проблемы были..